# Application Calling Error.cshtml in Development Server Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, runtime-error

I made a Dynamic website on ASP.Net MVC, Which working well in Local Machine but in Development Server it is not Working, Showing Message of Error.cshtml(Layout) Page instead of Login Page.
(And it Showing Script Error like Internal Server Error 500)
I'm Not Gettting What the Problem. 
Is It by This
- Added Authorization Filter
- Migrations
- any Changes in global.asax or Web.config

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to disable customErrors (set to Off) in web config - [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100)). Then you will see detailed error.

Comment: Yes! @Ivvan is right! In your web.config add <customErrors mode="Off"/> in<system.web> section & see detail error or post/edit it here.